# Edit Form Not Updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, state

I have a React Employee Management App. Currently I have all CRUD actions working except edit employee. When You click the edit button, you are taken to an edit form screen, and can enter all the input options, and submit the edit form. In the edit form, all the input fields show up in state, but when submitted, nothing is updating. 
https://github.com/PaperPlanes1623/react-employees

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Employees from './components/employee/Employees';
import EmployeeForm from './components/employee/EmployeeForm';
import index from './styles/index.scss';


class App extends Component {
  state = {
    employees: [
      { id: 1, firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Jones', email: 
'bob@email.com', phone: '801-555-5555' },
      { id: 2, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', email: 
'john@email.com', phone: '801-655-5555' },
      { id: 3, firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jane', email: 
'mary@email.com', phone: '801-755-5555' }
    ]
  }

  toggleEdit = () => this.setState({ editing: !this.state.editing });

  editEmployee = (employeeData, id) => {
    const employees = this.state.employees.map(employee => {
      if (employee.id === employeeData.id)
        return employeeData;
      return employee
    });
    this.setState({ employees })
  }

  getId = () => {
    // create unique id's
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
  };

  addEmployee = (employeeData) => {
    let newEmployee = { id: this.getId(), ...employeeData }
    this.setState({ employees: [newEmployee, 
...this.state.employees] })
  }

  removeEmployee = (id) => {
    const employees = this.state.employees.filter(employee => {
      if (employee.id !== id)
        return employee
    })
    this.setState({ employees: [...employees] })
  }

  render() {
    const { employees } = this.state
    return (
      <>
        <div class="head">
          Employee Management System
        </div>
        <EmployeeForm add={this.addEmployee} update= . 
       {this.editEmployee} />
        <div class="emp-header">
          All Employees
        </div>
        <Employees employees={employees} remove= . 
   {this.removeEmployee} update={this.editEmployee} edit= . 
   {this.toggleEdit} />
      </>
    )
  }
}




export default App;
```

EditForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class EditForm extends Component {

  state = { firstName: '', lastName: '', phone: '', email: '' };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.id)
      this.setState({
        firstName: this.props.firstName, lastName: 
this.props.lastName,
        phone: this.props.phone, email: this.props.email
      })
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.props.id) {
      this.props.update(this.state, this.props.id)
    } else {
      this.props.add(this.state)
    }
    this.setState({ firstname: '', lastName: '', phone: '', email: 
'' })
  }


  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1><strong>Edit Employee</strong></h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            placeholder="First Name"
            name="firstName"
            value={this.state.firstName}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          /><br /><br />
          <input
            placeholder="Last Name"
            name="lastName"
            value={this.state.lastName}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          /><br /><br />
          <input
            placeholder="phone"
            name="phone"
            value={this.state.phone}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          /><br /><br />
          <input
           placeholder="email"
            name="email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          /><br /><br />
          <Link to='/'>
            <input type="Submit" />
          </Link>
        </form>

      </>
    )
  }
}

export default EditForm;
```

Main.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import EditForm from './components/employee/EditForm';

const Main = () => (
   <Fragment>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route exact path="/edit" component={EditForm} />
    </Switch>
  </Fragment>
 )

export default Main;
```

Expected Results: Form updates original employees with new input values
Actual Results: Form Submits and redirects to main page, but nothing happens.

Comment: Hi Dylan, check the updated answer, and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is this,

```
<Link to='/'>
    <input type="Submit" />
</Link>
```

You are wrapping your `input` with `Link`, so whenever you click it will directly navigate to path `/` and not execute your `handleSubmit` function.

You should only have,

```
<input type="Submit" />   //Without wrapping with Link
```

**Note:** After submitting form, if you want to redirect to your home page, you can make use of [`Redirect`](https://medium.com/@anneeb/redirecting-in-react-4de5e517354a) from `react-route-dom` package.

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'


handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.props.id) {
      this.props.update(this.state, this.props.id)
    } else {
      this.props.add(this.state)
    }
    this.setState({ firstname: '', lastName: '', phone: '', email: '' })

    return <Redirect to="/" />  //Here you can redirect
}
```

Just replace your files with below,

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Employees from './components/employee/Employees';
import EmployeeForm from './components/employee/EmployeeForm';
import index from './styles/index.scss';


class App extends Component {
    state = {
        employees: [
            { id: 1, firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Jones', email: 'bob@email.com', phone: '801-555-5555' },
            { id: 2, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', email: 'john@email.com', phone: '801-655-5555' },
            { id: 3, firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jane', email: 'mary@email.com', phone: '801-755-5555' }
        ],
        updatedEmployee: '',
    }

    toggleEdit = () => this.setState({ editing: !this.state.editing });

    editEmployee = (employeeData) => {
        const employees = this.state.employees.map(employee => {
            if (employee.id === employeeData.id)
                return employeeData;
            return employee
        });
        this.setState({ employees })
    }

    updateEmployee = (id) => {
        const employees = this.state.employees.filter(employee => employee.id === id);
        this.setState({ updatedEmployee: employees[0] })
    }

    getId = () => {
        // create unique id's
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
            .toString(16)
            .substring(1);
    };

    addEmployee = (employeeData) => {
        let newEmployee = { id: this.getId(), ...employeeData }
        this.setState({ employees: [newEmployee, ...this.state.employees] })
    }

    removeEmployee = (id) => {
        const employees = this.state.employees.filter(employee => {
            if (employee.id !== id)
                return employee
        })
        this.setState({ employees: [...employees] })
    }

    render() {
        const { employees } = this.state
        return ( <
            >
            <div class="head">
          Employee Management System
        </div> <
            EmployeeForm add = { this.addEmployee } update = { this.editEmployee } updatedEmployee = { this.state.updatedEmployee }
            /> <
            div class = "emp-header" >
            All Employees <
            /div> <
            Employees employees = { employees } remove = { this.removeEmployee } update = { this.updateEmployee } edit = { this.toggleEdit }
            /> <
            />
        )
    }
}




export default App;
```

Employee.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Employee = ({ id, firstName, lastName, email, phone, remove, edit, update }) => (
  <tr id={id}>
    <td>{id}</td>
    <td>{firstName}</td>
    <td>{lastName}</td>
    <td>{email}</td>
    <td>{phone}</td>
    <td>
      <button class="delete-btn" onClick={() => remove(id)}>
        <strong>Delete</strong>
      </button>
        <button class="edit-btn" onClick={() => update(id)}>
          <strong>Edit</strong>
        </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
)

export default Employee;
```

Employees.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Employee from './Employee';

const Employees = ({ employees, remove, edit, update }) => (


  <div class="table">
    <Table celled padded>
      <Table.Header>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Employee ID</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>First Name</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Last Name</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Email</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Phone</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Options</Table.HeaderCell>
        </Table.Row>
      </Table.Header>
      <Table.Body>
        {
          employees.map(employee => (
            <Employee key={employee.id} {...employee} remove={remove} edit={edit} update={update}/>
          ))
        }
      </Table.Body>
    </Table>
  </div>
)

export default Employees;
```

EmployeeForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Divider } from 'semantic-ui-react';

class EmployeeForm extends Component {
  state = { 
    id: this.props.updatedEmployee.id, 
    firstName: this.props.updatedEmployee.firstName, 
    lastName: this.props.updatedEmployee.lastName, 
    email: this.props.updatedEmployee.email, 
    phone: this.props.updatedEmployee.phone 
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    this.setState({ [name]: value })
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //call add function
    if (this.props.updatedEmployee.id) {
      this.props.update(this.state)
    }else{
      this.props.add(this.state)
    }

    //clear out form 
    this.setState({ id: '', firstName: '', lastName: '', email: '', phone: '' })
  }

  componentDidUpdate(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.updatedEmployee.email !== this.props.updatedEmployee.email){
      this.setState({ 
    id: this.props.updatedEmployee.id, 
    firstName: this.props.updatedEmployee.firstName, 
    lastName: this.props.updatedEmployee.lastName, 
    email: this.props.updatedEmployee.email, 
    phone: this.props.updatedEmployee.phone 
  })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { firstName, lastName, phone, email } = this.state;
    return (
      <div class="form">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div class="form-head">
            <Divider horizontal>New Employee</Divider>
          </div>
          <input
            placeholder="First Name"
            required
            name="firstName"
            value={firstName}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          /><br /><br />
          <input
            placeholder="Last Name"
            required
            name="lastName"
            value={lastName}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          /><br /><br />
          <input
            placeholder="E-Mail"
            required
            name="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          /><br /><br />
          <input
            placeholder="Phone Number"
            required
            name="phone"
            value={phone}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          /><br /><br />
          <button class="submit-btn"><strong>Submit</strong></button>
          <br />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default EmployeeForm;
```

Comment: The Reason I added the router Link, was so I could redirect to the home page after submitting the form. When using your code provided, submitting stays on the edit form page. How could I redirect to the main page (not the EditForm page) after submitting?

Comment: ok I added the redirect from react router, and I am getting this error. TypeError: this.props.add is not a function. EditForm.handleSubmit
src/components/employee/EditForm.js:21

Comment: Can you show where you have added `EditForm` component?

Comment: Is `EditForm` component is `<EmployeeForm add={this.addEmployee} update={this.editEmployee} />`?

Comment: I added Main.js to the code, which shows where EditForm is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198212/discussion-between-ravibagul91-and-dylan-t).

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo error in your `handleSubmit` function.

not

```
this.props.edit(this.state, this.props.id)
```

should be

```
this.props.update(this.state, this.props.id)
```

`this.props.edit` only performs the toggle function, not save the updated.

Comment: Thanks. Just fixed the typo. The result is still the same. Values show up in state but upon submitting form nothing happens.

Comment: Could you see the updated result in Employee component?

Comment: No. The Employee component just displays the employee on the main page. After submitting EditForm I am redirected to the main page, but state still shows original employees.

Comment: It's because you use the e.preventDefault() function. This function stopped you to redirect to the main page.

Answer (score 0):

You’re passing `this.props.id` as the second argument to `this.props.update`, but in App.js `editEmployee` which you pass to the form as `update`) only takes one argument.

Try updating `editEmployee`’s signature to take an `id` argument.